# iPhone : How to display multiple colors in progress bar?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, ios4

I want to display multiple colors in progressbar.

for example,

Lets say there are three time portion in app.

Starting from `0 to 1 min` it should display `gray` color.

from `1 to 4 min` it should display `blue` color

and from `4 to 13 min` it should display `red` color.

So at the end progressbar should look with three color `gray,blue,red`.

How can I get multiple colors?

Comment: Hey I am not sure about the end of time ? The time is not fix it is random value ? How can I decide other progress bar's `X` ?

Comment: That's a bit of maths :) You have to cut the value in parts, then compute the scaled value appropriate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you target iOS5, use a custom background image for your UIProgressView (progressImage property).

Comment: will it keep different images ? I think it will replace image.